# ¿Por qué no funciona la comparación de IsNaN con el while cuando el usuario no introduce números, es decir, cuando introduce espacios o caracteres?

Tags: javascript

Deseo validar el ingreso de datos con un while y complementarlo con un switch y case, según se vayan dando las opciones que el usuario ingresará por el prompt mediante la variable declarada transaccionNumber. Si el numero ingresado es NaN, u otro caracter, o strings o tiene espacios la idea sería que salte un error como por ejemplo número no valido o una advertencia similar pero no logro saber por qué no funciona... ¿Estoy utilizando mal la estructura del while - switch?

```
//Simulacro base de datos de usuarios
let usuarios = [{
  name: 'Julia',
  lastName: 'Portobello',
  clave: 848402,
},
{
  name: 'Marcos',
  lastName: 'Filarmonica',
  clave: 461946,
},
{
  name: 'Julia',
  lastName: 'Roballos',
  clave: 849102,
}
]
/*---------------------------FUNCIONES_______--------------------*/
//Funcion swich
let transaccionSwitch = () => {
alert('Por favor a continuacion ingrese el numero de transaccion que desea realizar')
let transaccionNumber = Number(prompt('1-Deposito || 2- Transferencia'))
while (transaccionNumber != isNaN){
  switch (transaccionNumber) {
      case 1:
          alert('Deposito')
          deposito()
          break;
      case 2:
          alert('Transferencia')
          transferencia()
          break;
  }
}
console.log('HOla')    
}
//funcion deposito
let deposito = () => {
let numeroAdepositar = Number(prompt('Por favor ingrese la cantidad que desea depositar: '))
alert(`Su monto a depositar es de $ ${numeroAdepositar}`)
let movimientosDeposito = []
movimientosDeposito.push(numeroAdepositar)
console.log(movimientosDeposito)
return deposito;
}
//Funcion transferencia
let transferencia = () => {
let numeroAtransferir = Number(prompt('Por favor ingrese la cantidad que desea transferir: '))
alert(`Su monto es de $ ${numeroAtransferir}`)
return transferencia;
}
/*--------------------------------------------------------*/
//Programa bancario
alert('Bienvenido a Banco Comafi')
let ingresoClave = Number(prompt('Por favor ingrese su clave numerica: '))
if (ingresoClave === usuarios[0].clave) {
alert(`Bienvenid@ ${usuarios[0].name} ${usuarios[0].lastName} `)
transaccionSwitch()
} else if (ingresoClave === usuarios[1].clave) {
alert(`Bienvenida ${usuarios[1].name} ${usuarios[1].lastName} `)
transaccionSwitch()
} else if (ingresoClave === usuarios[2].clave) {
alert(`Bienvenida ${usuarios[2].name} ${usuarios[2].lastName} `)
transaccionSwitch()
}
```

Comment: isNaN Es una función, deberías usar `while (isNaN(transaccionNumber)) { ...`

Comment: Si @PabloLozano el problema está en que al hacer esto, me tilda error en el último cierre de llaves del else if

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partiendo de lo que tienes en tu código, comprendo que la idea del while es para que en caso de no ingresarse un número vuelva a solicitarlo, el problema es que no lo estás haciendo correctamente.

Pasa lo mismo con la funcion isNaN, te comparto el código corregido y comentando los pasos requeridos para que comprendas un poco más el flujo.

Te comparto enlaces donde puedes apoyarte para que comprendas como funciona la funcion isNaN y en que casos puede retornar true o false:

[isNaN referencia 1](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

Mas ejemplos:
[isNaN referencia 2](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp)

```js
//Simulacro base de datos de usuarios
let usuarios = [{
    name: 'Julia',
    lastName: 'Portobello',
    clave: 848402,
  },
  {
    name: 'Marcos',
    lastName: 'Filarmonica',
    clave: 461946,
  },
  {
    name: 'Julia',
    lastName: 'Roballos',
    clave: 849102,
  }
];

const deposito = () => {
  /*****/
};

const transferencia = () => {
  /*****/
};

/*---------------------------FUNCIONES_______--------------------*/
//Funcion swich
const transaccionSwitch = () => {
  alert('Por favor a continuacion ingrese el numero de transaccion que desea realizar');
  // Creamos booleano encargado de validar si es un número válido o no
  let numberInvalid = false;
  do {
    const transaccionNumber = Number(prompt('1- Deposito || 2- Transferencia'));

    // Validamos si la opción ingresada es un número
    numberInvalid = isNaN(transaccionNumber);

    // Comprobamos el número ingresado, si es un número que no está entre las opciones entra al default
    switch (transaccionNumber) {
      case 1:
        alert('Deposito');
        deposito();
        break;
      case 2:
        alert('Transferencia');
        transferencia();
        break;
      default:
        alert('Opción no permitida, por favor ingrese una opción válida.');
        // Aunque sea un número válido, obligamos a que se ingrese uno de los números que se dan en la opción.
        numberInvalid = true;
        break;
    }
    // Si es true, repite el proceso y solicita nuevamente ingresar la opción.
  } while (numberInvalid);
}

transaccionSwitch();
```

Espero te sirva, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

NO comprendo para que necesitas el while,simplemente valida que es un numero y pasalo al switch directamente

```
   let transaccionNumber=parseInt(<tu variable>);
if(isNaN(transaccionNumber)){
alert("no soy numero");
}else{
switch (transaccionNumber) {
          case 1:
              alert('Deposito')
              deposito()
              break;
          case 2:
              alert('Transferencia')
              transferencia()
              break;
      }
}
```

Comment: y que hace esto? como resuelve el problema?. Por favor lee [answer]

Comment: No se para que necesitas el while,actualice la respuesta segun la necesidad @OtroMasComoTu